# Best Practice for angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic3

My question is simple.

I'm working on adding an angular directive to a small project, but several options out there show projects with Controllers and Services JS files that help to implement the directive.
Which approach is better?

A- The single Directive.ts or. js file or 
B- The Multiple files approach with Controllers and Services.

Or am I missing something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very high level question, I'd try to give very high level answer.

Approach depends upon scope of functionality you want to achieve through directive/component.
If its mere local field validation, then just .ts file is enough (you should think about using [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) as well for these scenarios.

If there is any remote validation, then prefer using services for re-usability prospective.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for letting me pick your brain. I'll give Pipes a  try.